# How to use curl to follow a url and then login at the redirected final page and verify that login worked?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to provide a url to Curl. Curl will follow all redirects until it lands a login page. Here curl should login with the provided username and password. If the login is successful it should give a "login successfull" message otherwise "login failure". 
I have tried this in php but no luck. I have little experience with Curl, so any help is appreciated. Can anyone point out the problem with the below code?
When I run this, I get the "Not found" error.

```
             <html>
             <head>
              <title>Test Login</title>
             </head>
             <body>

             TEST LOGIN :


             <?php
            $data = array(
                'username' => 'admin2',
                'password' => 'admin',
                );

                $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                $options = array(
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,      // return web page
                        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,     // do not return headers
                        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,      // follow redirects
                        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $useragent, // who am i
                        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,       // set referer on redirect
                        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 9,          // timeout on connect (in seconds)
                        CURLOPT_POST           => true,       // do a regular post
                        CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH => true,
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data, // posting the username & pass
                        // CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => cookie.txt, 
                        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 9,          // timeout on response (in seconds)
                        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,         // stop after 10 redirects
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,     // SSL verification not required
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,     // SSL verification not required
                );


                    // echo $link->getAttribute('href');
                    // $link->getAttribute('href')


                    $ch = curl_init('https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.ac.uk:8101/application');
                    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
                    curl_exec( $ch );

                    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    if (200==$httpcode) {
                        echo '  ';
                        echo '<img src="green-tick-trans.png" alt="Passed" height="15" width="15">';
                        // echo $httpcode;
                    } else {
                        echo '  ';
                        echo '<img src="red_cross.png" alt="Failed" height="15" width="15">';
                        // echo $httpcode;
                    }
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo 'Result: <br>';
                    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
                    echo 'Info: <br>';
                    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                    // curl_close ($ch); 

                    print_r($result);
                    print_r($info);
            ?>

             </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Is this a real working case or are you trying to test something?

Comment: Its a real working case, where my ultimate aim is to check a list of URLs and mark them valid or invalid based on the login test.